# doc.LoadXml giving error data at the root level is invalid

Tags: c#, xml

I am having xml response like below

```
       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <CreateMeetMeOrWebMeetingResults 
xmlns:ns2="coss-ws-common">
<transactionId>z8kflt5fi2x28vd51</transactionId>
<status>OK</status>
<meetme id="178635601">
    <billingCode>MR5942965</billingCode>
    <confirmationId>Q-1GFR347H6I</confirmationId>
    <serviceId>1021</serviceId>
    <serviceName>BT MeetMe</serviceName>
    <timezone>America/New_York</timezone>
    <topic>Danny Chung</topic>
    <chairpasscode>34132738</chairpasscode>
    <participantpasscode>84781442</participantpasscode>
    <dialInNumber>
        <phoneType>PSTN</phoneType>
        <formattedNumber>0203 463 9676</formattedNumber>
        <displayName>Direct: 0203 463 9676</displayName>
        <rawNumber>02034639676</rawNumber>
    </dialInNumber>
    <createDate>2014-11-25T09:34:33.168Z</createDate>
    <createdByApplicationId>1120</createdByApplicationId>
    <bridgeId>892</bridgeId>
    <recurringFlag>false</recurringFlag>
    <globalAccessFeature locked="false" enabled="true">
        <url>Please contact help desk</url>
    </globalAccessFeature>
    <meetingType>MEETME</meetingType>
    <serviceType>MEETME</serviceType>
    <pendingBlackoutDateApproval>false</pendingBlackoutDateApproval>
    <chairpersonRecord locked="false" enabled="true"/>
</meetme>
 </CreateMeetMeOrWebMeetingResults>
```

I am trying to convert it into xml by doc.LoadXml(response) and its giving error for invalid data at root level.
if somebody can help to solve the issue

Comment: Well you don't appear to have a closing tag for the root element... and I'm not *sure* whether you're allowed whitespace before the XML declaration.

Comment: Where's you're code? How are you reading the file?

Comment: @jon I am having closing tag in response "</CreateMeetMeOrWebMeetingResults>" . I missed it while copying here.

Comment: Please take more care in the future then. So, the next potential problem is the whitespace at the start of the document. Is *that* present in your real file?

Comment: @Frank i am having a string and getting response in string and trying to parse it into xml

Comment: @NituBansal: "I am having a string" doesn't say *anything* about where you're getting the string from, or how you're trying to parse it. Ideally, you should show a short but complete program demonstrating the problem. Please read http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints

Comment: Yeah, I understand you're trying that, but I don't know how you're trying it. Show the code you are using here at this thread below your xml data.

Comment: Also fix your xml that is displayed. Or you'll keep getting questions about your closing tag. Select the word `edit` below your post and edit it.

Answer (score 1):

If that is your *complete* xml, you missed a **closing tag**:

```
</CreateMeetMeOrWebMeetingResults>
```

Try adding it at the bottom of your xml

Looking at your indentation, could be that your xml starts with a whitespace. This could be another reason

Comment: i checked indentation, it is correct. there is some other problem while parsing.

Comment: have you checked the closing tag? </CreateMeetMeOrWebMeetingResults>

Answer (score -1):

You don't seem to have a root element for your xml.  This works for me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<root>
    <CreateMeetMeOrWebMeetingResults xmlns:ns2="coss-ws-common"/>
    <transactionId>z8kflt5fi2x28vd51</transactionId>
    <status>OK</status>
    <meetme id="178635601">
        <billingCode>MR5942965</billingCode>
        <confirmationId>Q-1GFR347H6I</confirmationId>
        <serviceId>1021</serviceId>
        <serviceName>BT MeetMe</serviceName>
        <timezone>America/New_York</timezone>
        <topic>Danny Chung</topic>
        <chairpasscode>34132738</chairpasscode>
        <participantpasscode>84781442</participantpasscode>
        <dialInNumber>
            <phoneType>PSTN</phoneType>
            <formattedNumber>0203 463 9676</formattedNumber>
            <displayName>Direct: 0203 463 9676</displayName>
            <rawNumber>02034639676</rawNumber>
        </dialInNumber>
        <createDate>2014-11-25T09:34:33.168Z</createDate>
        <createdByApplicationId>1120</createdByApplicationId>
        <bridgeId>892</bridgeId>
        <recurringFlag>false</recurringFlag>
        <globalAccessFeature locked="false" enabled="true">
            <url>Please contact help desk</url>
        </globalAccessFeature>
        <meetingType>MEETME</meetingType>
        <serviceType>MEETME</serviceType>
        <pendingBlackoutDateApproval>false</pendingBlackoutDateApproval>
        <chairpersonRecord locked="false" enabled="true"/>
    </meetme>
</root>
```

Comment: CreateMeetMeOrWebMeetingResults is the root element.